# Using raster calculator in ModelBuilder to batch reclassify hundreds of rasters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, reclassify, maxent

I'm attempting to use iterate by raster to feed all the files through a simple map algebra expression (I'm looking at data that indicates probability of salamander habitat) so I want to reclassify the raster data and get output that separates 0 probability of habitat vs. greater than 0 probability.

After many hours of geoprocessing, I just realized that all the habitat extents are identical.

[image: ModelBuilder Diagram]

```py
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# reclassifymodel.txt
# Created on: 2013-12-02 05:29:53.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: reclassifymodel <SalamanderData> 
# Description: 
# This model reclassifies all TIF rasters to binary probability
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")

# Script arguments
SalamanderData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if SalamanderData == '#' or not SalamanderData:
    SalamanderData = "C:\\Users\\mkcar_000\\Desktop\\SalamanderData" # provide a default       value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Raster = SalamanderData
reclassified = Raster
polygon = reclassified
polyselect = polygon
extent__Name_feat_shp = polyselect
pathname = Raster
Name = SalamanderData

# Process: Iterate Rasters
arcpy.IterateRasters_mb(SalamanderData, "", "TIF", "RECURSIVE")

# Process: Parse Path
arcpy.ParsePath_mb(Raster, "PATH")

# Process: Raster Calculator
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("outraster = Con(\"%Raster%\" > 0, 1, 0)", reclassified)

# Process: Raster to Polygon
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(reclassified, polygon, "SIMPLIFY", "Value")

# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(polygon, polyselect, "\"grid_code\" = 1")

# Process: Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polyselect, extent__Name_feat_shp, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your `Select tool` which only selects `grid_code= 1`. The `Select Tool` selects only what you tell it to select and leaves everything else behind. Therefore with your `Copy Feature` you are only saving `grid_code=1` but nothing else.

```py
# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(polygon, polyselect, "\"grid_code\" = 1")
```