# Why is Modelbuilder Raster Calculator only exporting black and white?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator

I am attempting to create in ArcGIS 10.3 a Modelbuilder code based partially on that in [Using raster calculator in ModelBuilder to batch reclassify hundreds of rasters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79188)  My code will run through 70+ rasters of different sizes, raster calc them from meters to feet, place them in a specific directory, and eventually iterate both a polygon from raster boundary, two separate contour maps, and add a field and an attribute to each of the polygon boundaries. However, I am encountering a problem in just creating the Raster Calculator iteration.

Here is my Modelbuilder as currently drafted:
[image: Modelbuilder Layout]

Its code:

```py
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")

# Script arguments
Test_Group = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Test_Group == '#' or not Test_Group:
Test_Group = "N:\\Planning And Development\\Engineering\\Systemwide GIS\\Geodatabases\\Comprehensive\\Test Group" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Name = "USGS_NED_one_meter_x46y443_CO_SoPlatteRiver_Lot5_2013_IMG_2015.img"
feet__Name_ = "N:\\Planning And Development\\Engineering\\Systemwide GIS\\Geodatabases\\TestOutput\\feet_%Name%"
Raster = "N:\\Planning And Development\\Engineering\\Systemwide GIS\\Geodatabases\\Comprehensive\\Test Group\\USGS_NED_one_meter_x46y443_CO_SoPlatteRiver_Lot5_2013_IMG_2015.img"
Value = "USGS_NED_one_meter_x46y443_CO_SoPlatteRiver_Lot5_2013_IMG_2015.img"

# Process: Iterate Rasters
arcpy.IterateRasters_mb(Test_Group, "", "", "RECURSIVE")

# Process: Raster Calculator
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("\"%Name%\" *  3.28", feet__Name_)

# Process: Parse Path
arcpy.ParsePath_mb(Raster, "FILE")
```

Here is the Raster Calculator setup (ignore the error message, that was after I ran through an iteration):
[image: RasterCalculator]

Output comes out like this:
[image: B/W output]

Strangely if I run an individual instance of Raster Calculator, it comes out in greyscale as normal. However, with 70+ rasters I don't want to do one at a time especially since I want to automate other tasks after I have solved this error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out if the calculated raster values (just one sample each, model builder and manual) are the same?

Comment: Both the manual and the MB calculations have the same range output. Is there any other way to check the values?

Comment: Here is a picture of the two. Feet_ is the modelbuilder execution, Feet2_ was an independent Raster Calculator session:
http://imgur.com/Wb7t46B

Answer (score 1):

After your comments, I think your issue is related to not having a histogram to show your raster as desired. If you add [Calculate Statistics tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) after **Raster Calculator** output, you should be able to see them rendered correctly.

Comment: I attempted this, with a CS tool running after RC as recommended, and it produces the same output as without the CS tool.

Also, I noticed this interesting characteristic. The input are wildly different sizes, but the input both came out in the same file size:

[Input](http://imgur.com/pSgdJfF)
[Output](http://imgur.com/ZLJ1Xr8)